# Recaptcha - need only one word

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha on my site and it is working fine.  Only problem is that just because there are two words, it is getting difficult and time taking process. So I want to show one word of captcha instead of two.  The question is can we somehow tell the recaptcha to just show one word, rather then two?

It is urgent so please try to suggest me the solution as soon as possible.

**Problem:** Once i got recaptcha with language "URDU". So is there any way where i can define that i want recaptcha in english only.

Thanks
Tanu

Comment: Recaptcha will always show you 2 words (it's at the core of their technology), use other captcha provider or library, if you want one word.

Comment: Thanks.. Can you please suggest me some other service with one word or simple captcha.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of reCaptcha is to have two words - the other word is known, the other must be identified by the user. This is the method reCaptcha uses to decipher unknown words. So no, there is no way to have reCaptcha display only one word as that would defeat its purpose.

> Scanned text is subjected to analysis by two different optical character recognition programs; in cases where the programs disagree, the questionable word is converted into a CAPTCHA. The word is displayed along with a control word already known. The system assumes that if the human types the control word correctly, the questionable word is also correct.